# How to create a list of users correctly?

Tags: php, html, arrays, string, mysqli

Hello i have created a simple user list by results in database, and i have two problems with it..

I receive on my list like this:

[UserOne, ...][UserTwo, ...]

But i need to receive like this:

[UserOne],[UserTwo]...

And by the three dots i need to limit the results to 20 for example and then set the three dots.

Image: https://prntscr.com/huj1e4

Look my code:

```
 $PageSqla = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE status = 'online' ORDER BY nome ASC ";
                 $jogadoresonline = mysqli_query($connectionae, $PageSqla);
                echo "<div class='bundinhabonita'>Players online - (".mysqli_num_rows($jogadoresonline).")</div>";


                 if(mysqli_fetch_array($jogadoresonline)){
                     foreach($jogadoresonline as $merda){

                              if($merda['grupo'] == "CEO"){
                     $mimimi = "<span style='font-weight: bold;color: #D9A334;background: transparent url(https://i.imgur.com/DeeiUkd.gif); text-shadow: #000000 1px 1px 3px;'><a href='usuario?nome=".$merda['nome']."'>".$merda['nome']."</a></span><span style='color: black;'>, </span>";
                      }elseif($merda['grupo'] == "Manager"){
                     $mimimi = "<span style='font-weight: bold;color: #aa0000;background: transparent url(https://i.imgur.com/DeeiUkd.gif); text-shadow: #000000 1px 1px 3px;'><a href='usuario?nome=".$merda['nome']."'>".$merda['nome']."</a></span><span style='color: black;'>, </span>";
                      }elseif($merda['grupo'] == "Admin"){
                     $mimimi = "<span style='font-weight: bold;color: #ff5555;background: transparent url(https://i.imgur.com/DeeiUkd.gif); text-shadow: #000000 1px 1px 3px;'><a href='usuario?nome=".$merda['nome']."'>".$merda['nome']."</a></span><span style='color: black;'>, </span>";
                      }elseif($merda['grupo'] == "Moderator"){
                     $mimimi = "<span style='font-weight: bold;color: #00aa00;background: transparent url(https://i.imgur.com/DeeiUkd.gif); text-shadow: #000000 1px 1px 3px;'><a href='usuario?nome=".$merda['nome']."'>".$merda['nome']."</a></span><span style='color: black;'>, </span>";
                      }elseif($merda['grupo'] == "Helper"){
                     $mimimi = "<span style='font-weight: bold;color: #E3D628;background: transparent url(https://i.imgur.com/DeeiUkd.gif); text-shadow: #000000 1px 1px 3px;'><a href='usuario?nome=".$merda['nome']."'>".$merda['nome']."</a></span><span style='color: black;'>, </span>";
                      }elseif($merda['grupo'] == "Builder"){
                     $mimimi = "<span style='font-weight: bold;color: #3F3FFE;background: transparent url(https://i.imgur.com/DeeiUkd.gif); text-shadow: #000000 1px 1px 3px;'><a href='usuario?nome=".$merda['nome']."'>".$merda['nome']."</a></span><span style='color: black;'>, </span>";
                      }elseif($merda['grupo'] == "YouTuber"){
                     $mimimi = "<span style='font-weight: bold;color: #ff5555; text-shadow: #000000 1px 1px 3px;'><a href='usuario?nome=".$merda['nome']."'>".$merda['nome']."</a></span><span style='color: black;'>, </span>";
                      }elseif($merda['grupo'] == "MVP+"){
                     $mimimi = "<span style='font-weight: bold;color: #3ffe3f; text-shadow: #000000 1px 1px 3px;'><a href='usuario?nome=".$merda['nome']."'>".$merda['nome']."</a></span><span style='color: black;'>, </span>";
                      }elseif($merda['grupo'] == "MVP"){
                     $mimimi = "<span style='font-weight: bold;color: #00aa00; text-shadow: #000000 1px 1px 3px;'><a href='usuario?nome=".$merda['nome']."'>".$merda['nome']."</a></span><span style='color: black;'>, </span>";
                      }elseif($merda['grupo'] == "VIP+"){
                     $mimimi = "<span style='font-weight: bold;color: #be00be; text-shadow: #000000 1px 1px 3px;'><a href='usuario?nome=".$merda['nome']."'>".$merda['nome']."</a></span><span style='color: black;'>, </span>";
                      }elseif($merda['grupo'] == "VIP"){
                     $mimimi = "<span style='font-weight: bold;color: #00bebe; text-shadow: #000000 1px 1px 3px;'><a href='usuario?nome=".$merda['nome']."'>".$merda['nome']."</a></span><span style='color: black;'>, </span>";
                      }elseif($merda['grupo'] == "Member"){
                     $mimimi = "<span style='font-weight: bold;color: #bebebe; text-shadow: #000000 1px 1px 3px;'><a href='usuario?nome=".$merda['nome']."'>".$merda['nome']."</a></span><span style='color: black;'>, </span>";
                      }             



                    echo $mimimi."<span style='color: black;'>...</span>";


                     }


                 }else{
                     echo "<div style='color: grey;'>None is online.</div>";
                 }
```

Comment: echo $mimimi."<span style='color: black;'>...</span>"; Remove those 3 dots.

Comment: Yeah, but how can i limit all those results and then set 3 dots at the end on the last resulted?

Answer (score 0):

As said by @halojoy in comment, the three dots "..." are in a span in your code. You've put this code in a foreach loop, so the dots are written at every iteration.

I'll try  to use the almost same code as yours in the solution:

```
<?php
$PageSqla = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE status = 'online' ORDER BY nome ASC LIMIT 0,20"; //Note the limit to 20 elements
$jogadoresonline = mysqli_query($connectionae, $PageSqla);
echo "<div class='bundinhabonita'>Players online - (".mysqli_num_rows($jogadoresonline).")</div>";


if(mysqli_fetch_array($jogadoresonline)){
    foreach($jogadoresonline as $merda){
        if($merda['grupo'] == "CEO"){
            mimimi = "<span style='font-weight: bold;color: #D9A334;background: transparent url(https://i.imgur.com/DeeiUkd.gif); text-shadow: #000000 1px 1px 3px;'><a href='usuario?nome=".$merda['nome']."'>".$merda['nome']."</a></span><span style='color: black;'>, </span>";
        } elseif($merda['grupo'] == "Manager"){
            $mimimi = "<span style='font-weight: bold;color: #aa0000;background: transparent url(https://i.imgur.com/DeeiUkd.gif); text-shadow: #000000 1px 1px 3px;'><a href='usuario?nome=".$merda['nome']."'>".$merda['nome']."</a></span><span style='color: black;'>, </span>";
        } elseif($merda['grupo'] == "Admin"){
            $mimimi = "<span style='font-weight: bold;color: #ff5555;background: transparent url(https://i.imgur.com/DeeiUkd.gif); text-shadow: #000000 1px 1px 3px;'><a href='usuario?nome=".$merda['nome']."'>".$merda['nome']."</a></span><span style='color: black;'>, </span>";
        } elseif($merda['grupo'] == "Moderator"){
            $mimimi = "<span style='font-weight: bold;color: #00aa00;background: transparent url(https://i.imgur.com/DeeiUkd.gif); text-shadow: #000000 1px 1px 3px;'><a href='usuario?nome=".$merda['nome']."'>".$merda['nome']."</a></span><span style='color: black;'>, </span>";
        } elseif($merda['grupo'] == "Helper"){
            $mimimi = "<span style='font-weight: bold;color: #E3D628;background: transparent url(https://i.imgur.com/DeeiUkd.gif); text-shadow: #000000 1px 1px 3px;'><a href='usuario?nome=".$merda['nome']."'>".$merda['nome']."</a></span><span style='color: black;'>, </span>";
        } elseif($merda['grupo'] == "Builder"){
            $mimimi = "<span style='font-weight: bold;color: #3F3FFE;background: transparent url(https://i.imgur.com/DeeiUkd.gif); text-shadow: #000000 1px 1px 3px;'><a href='usuario?nome=".$merda['nome']."'>".$merda['nome']."</a></span><span style='color: black;'>, </span>";
        } elseif($merda['grupo'] == "YouTuber"){
             $mimimi = "<span style='font-weight: bold;color: #ff5555; text-shadow: #000000 1px 1px 3px;'><a href='usuario?nome=".$merda['nome']."'>".$merda['nome']."</a></span><span style='color: black;'>, </span>";
        } elseif($merda['grupo'] == "MVP+"){
              $mimimi = "<span style='font-weight: bold;color: #3ffe3f; text-shadow: #000000 1px 1px 3px;'><a href='usuario?nome=".$merda['nome']."'>".$merda['nome']."</a></span><span style='color: black;'>, </span>";
        } elseif($merda['grupo'] == "MVP"){
             $mimimi = "<span style='font-weight: bold;color: #00aa00; text-shadow: #000000 1px 1px 3px;'><a href='usuario?nome=".$merda['nome']."'>".$merda['nome']."</a></span><span style='color: black;'>, </span>";
        } elseif($merda['grupo'] == "VIP+"){
             $mimimi = "<span style='font-weight: bold;color: #be00be; text-shadow: #000000 1px 1px 3px;'><a href='usuario?nome=".$merda['nome']."'>".$merda['nome']."</a></span><span style='color: black;'>, </span>";
        } elseif($merda['grupo'] == "VIP"){
             $mimimi = "<span style='font-weight: bold;color: #00bebe; text-shadow: #000000 1px 1px 3px;'><a href='usuario?nome=".$merda['nome']."'>".$merda['nome']."</a></span><span style='color: black;'>, </span>";
        } elseif($merda['grupo'] == "Member"){
             $mimimi = "<span style='font-weight: bold;color: #bebebe; text-shadow: #000000 1px 1px 3px;'><a href='usuario?nome=".$merda['nome']."'>".$merda['nome']."</a></span><span style='color: black;'>, </span>";
        }             
     }
     echo $mimimi."<span style='color: black;'>...</span>";

 } else{
     echo "<div style='color: grey;'>None is online.</div>";
 }
```

As you can see in the code, it's almost the same as yours. The only modifications are:

- `LIMIT 0,20` in the SQL query. So it takes the 20 first elements, or less if there are not at least 20 elements.
- I moved the '...' after the foreach, so it shows your results and only then it displays the dots.